# Unable to raise the toast for the date iam receving from server and showing in the date TextView?

Tags: java, android, listview, baseadapter

```
public class Trip Adapter  extends Base Adapter {
    private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;

        Context context;
        private  final DailyTrips dailyTrips;
        private  final ArrayList<Trip> trip;
        public static final String PREFS_NAME3= "MyPrefs" ;
        Context pref;
        TextView dateTextView;
    String Day;
        public String Date;
        String Distance;
        String speed;

       // private Context mContext;
        public TripAdapter(DailyTrips dailyTrips, ArrayList<Trip> trip) {

            this.dailyTrips=dailyTrips;
            this.trip=trip;
            context= dailyTrips;
            inflater = ( LayoutInflater )context.
                    getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);


        }


        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return trip.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {

            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            //Holder holder=new Holder();

            View rowView;
            MyViewHolder mViewHolder;

            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_trip, parent, false);
                mViewHolder = new MyViewHolder(convertView);
                convertView.setTag(mViewHolder);
            } else {
                mViewHolder = (MyViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            Trip trips=trip.get(position);

            Day=trips.Day;
          Date=trips.Date;
            Distance=trips.Distance;
             speed=trips.speed;
           // day.setText(Day);
            //speedTextView.setText(Date);

            return convertView;
        }

        private class MyViewHolder {
            TextView day,date,distance,averagespeed;
            ImageView ivIcon;

            public MyViewHolder(View item) {
               day = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.dayTextView);
//saving date//                date = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.dateTextView);
                distance = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.distanceTextView);
                averagespeed = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.AverageSpeed);
                day.setText(Day);
                date.setText(Date);
                distance.setText(Distance);
                averagespeed.setText(speed);


            }
        }


            }
```

Comment: where you show toast?

Comment: that is what i am confused that i will be showing it in base adapter class or the main activity class?? and where will i get the the onitem click listner??

Comment: @purva: `where will i get the the onitem click listner?` in MainActivity